# ASP.NET CORE Automapper Profile with Scoped Dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, automapper

In my usecase i need to map a property based on context.
Keep in mind, I use Automapper with the Entity Framework by calling the `ProjectTo` function. So a custom value resolver is sadly no option.

simple example:

```cs
public class Comment 
{
  public int Id { get;set; }
  public int UserId { get;set; }
  ...
}

public class Source 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments  { get; set; }
}

public class Destination 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int NumOwnComments { get; set; }
}
```

Basicly the Destination should contain the number of own comments.
The Current user is dynamicly resolved using an `ICurrentUserService` with a property `UserId`.

I have solved the issue the following way:

In the `Startup.cs` I added a `Transient` Mapper / Configuration.

```
  services.AddTransient(provider => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile(provider.GetService<ICurrentUserService>())); })
        .CreateMapper());
```

In the MappingProfile I then created the mapping the following way:

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile {

    public MappingProfile(ICurrentUserService currentUserService) {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.NumOwnComments, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Comments.Count(c => c.UserId == currentUserService.UserId))
        ;
    }
}
```

While this works, having the mapper configuration as transient / scoped dependency is not great. Every request creates this mapper and this consumes a whole lot of memory and cpu cycles.

Is there a more elegant way like creating the mapping profile as singleton and then execute it in a scoped / transient mapper?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: Wow how could I miss that... thanks will try it out. Do you have any recommendation how to manage parameters through out a project? Custom ProjectTo Extension Methods like `ProjectToDestinationDto(currentUser)`?

Comment: That should work. Give it a shot :)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked well & solved my performance problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question for future reference:

Thanks to @lucian-bargaoanu for providing the link in the comments: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Dynamic parameters can be passed via the ProjectTo method.

I ended up creating extension methods for all my DTO Projections

```cs
public static class DestinationProjection 
{
    public static IQueryable<Destination> ProjectToDestination(IQueryable source, IConfiguration configuration, int currentUserId) {
        return source.ProjectTo<Destination>(configuration, new { currentUserId });
    }
}
```

And in the mapping I used this parameter

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile 
{
    public MappingProfile() {
        int? currentUserId = null;
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.NumOwnComments, opts => opts.MapFrom(s => s.Comments.Count(c => c.UserId == currentUserId.GetValueOrDefault()))
        ;
    }
}
```

This way I can inject my `ICurrentUserService` in the handler class.

```
public class DestinationListQueryHandler  
{
    public DestinationListQueryHandler(IMapper mapper, IDbContext dbContext, ICurrentUserService currentUserService) 
    {
         // field initialization logic
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Destination>> Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await dbContext.Sources.ProjectToDestination(mapper.ConfigurationProvider, currentUserId).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue and ended up with custom IValueResolver for UserId property

```cs
public class UserIdResolver : IValueResolver<object, object, string>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public UserIdResolver(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public string Resolve(object source, object destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
        return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserContext>().Id;
    }
}
```

And usage like this

```cs
class CustomProfile : Profile
{
    public CustomProfile()
    {
         CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom<UserIdResolver>());
    }
}
```